# How to implement a Google map store locator

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, google-maps

I have followed the following Google developer doc about creating a store locator usng PHP & MySql.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

I have this working but now I would like to integrate this with an existing Wordpress installation.

My problem with integrating this, is the way WP stores repeatable custom fields. I have a repeatable field to enter multiple markers per custom post type. WP stores this as serialised data within the DB.

I cannot see a way of using the Haversine formula select statement mentioned in the doc to perform the radius search based on an entered postcode. I know there are various Google Map plugins out there, but I can't find any that will:

- Add multiple markers per custom post
- Provide a search to list markers within a radius of an entered
  postcode

Has anyone got any suggestions how I can do this, or does these features exist?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a similar custom store locator for a client, and what I ended up doing was saving each lat / lon pair as post meta for a single `location` post type, and then assigning each `location` post type to a parent `store` post type. that way, a single store could have multiple unique locations. location posts were hidden in admin and managed via a custom meta box within the store post type.

Comment: Ok this sounds like an ideal solution. How do I go about assigning a location to a parent and also I cant see away to manage these within a different post type? Any tutorials or help on this? Thanks

Comment: @Robert the posts table has a `post_parent` field you can use to store the ID on [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). there is no UI for managing a post type within another, I had to create it using [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), a bit of [javascript](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to manage fields, and the API to [insert](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) / [update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) location posts.

Comment: Ok thats great I will give this a shot and let you know how I get on.